# Catch Nan and Inf in Windows C++

Tags: c++, math

I painfully learned today that **Nan** and **Inf** have serious side issues. Did you know for example that sqrtf(NaN) is more than **15 times slower** and sqrtf(-1) is **30 times slower** (!!)  than sqrtf(10.123132) - which is on its own a quite slow, floating point calculation!? You calculate rubbish, need ridiculous amounts of time for it and don't even realize it.

Ok, under Linux you can catch Nan and Inf bugs by throwing an exception when they occur:

```
#include <fenv.h> 
feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
```

How could you achieve that under Windows?

EDIT:
the Benchmarking code:

```
float a,b;
a = 1.0 / 0;   //inf
a = -10;         //also nice
long c=0;
long time = SDL_GetTicks();

for (long i=1;i<=1000000;i++) {
   b=sqrt(a); 
}

ostringstream Help; Help << SDL_GetTicks()-time;

//RESULT SHEET
//sqrt(1): 21ms
//sqrt(10): 21ms
//sqrt(10.123): 20ms
//sqrt(-10);   390ms
//sqrt(+-NaN): 174ms
//sqrt(inf):  174
```

Comment: how did you measure that time? Maybe instead of hiding exception you should just prevent the occurence?

Comment: Use `isinf()` and `isnan()` to check the value? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308344.aspx

Comment: You turn on exceptions with _controlfp()

Comment: You do exactly the same as under Linux, unmask the exceptions. Surely a quick web search would have yielded that information.

Comment: I can't reproduce your timings on my laptop (core i5, ubuntu, gcc). What hardware/OS are you using and how did you benchmark?

Comment: I'd say the speed issue is a red herring, judicious checking for NaN/Inf is the end, and enabling those exceptions is the means.

Comment: Hi, Michal-szczygiel, I would like to prevent them but for that I have to find them first. Hi @DavidHeffernan , does this library exist under Windows? rici, I added the benchmark for you. 5 ms go for the plain loop, the rest ms are the calculation. Its a g++ compiler on an up-to-date Linux system violet-giraffe, yeah, but then I would have to clutter the whole program with these commands, what I do not want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can turn on floating point exceptions using the `/fp:except` option.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx.

The equivalent in code is `#pragma float_control( except, on )`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6(v=vs.110).aspx.

At runtime you can use something like `_controlfp( _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM )`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e9b52ceh(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I would like to use a basic editor (geany etc) - _controlfp sounds promising. Any library links needed for that?

Comment: I believe it's part of the crt.  Should be easy to try and see.

Comment: @NateHekman `#pragma float_control` and `/fp:accept` affect code generation, not whether floating point exceptions are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For me (only) the _controlfp approach worked, I used the "safe" implementation, namely:

```
 unsigned int current_word = 0; 
 _controlfp_s(&current_word, _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_INEXACT, _MCW_EM); // raise exception on NaN (0xF)
```

the #pragma and /fp:except did not have any (/the desired) effect in my code (which consists of C code integrated into a C++ project).

Or, shorter - just kick out the _EM_INVALID flag to make NaN raise exception:

```
unsigned int current_word = 0; 
_controlfp_s(&current_word, 0, _EM_INVALID); // raise exception on NaN (set 0x10 bit to false)
```

Comment: Yeah, the previous answerer didn't seem to understand the distinction between code generation and control of the floating point state. Note, however, that `/fp:except` can *also* be important, if you want to disable optimizations which could affect whether a given operation raises an exception. (This wouldn't be useful for performance targeted testing.)

Comment: Okay that explains why the two other suggestions didn't work out for me - thanks for clarifying!